# Test if a single object matches a Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#

I have a single object (a record from a database) and want to check if this object matches a given condition in the form of `Func<T, bool>`.

I solved this by adding the object to a list of objects, and try to get it from this list with a where clause, given the condition like this

```cs
var testMatch = new Test
{
    t1 = "123"
};

// Query is stored in a string and compiled with Sprint.Filter.OData to p => p.t1 == "123"
var query = "t1 eq '123'";
var compiledQuery = Filter.Deserialize<Test>(query).Compile();

// This works like expected
Console.WriteLine(Match<Test>(compiledQuery, testMatch));

public bool Match<T>(Func<T, bool> condition, T testObject)
{
    var test = new List<T>();
    test.Add(testObject);
    var t = test.Where(condition).FirstOrDefault();
    return (t != null);
}

public class Test
{
    public string t1 {get; set;}
}
```

So this works like expected, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to test a single object than creating a list, adding it to this list and try to retrieve it with the condition.

Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just say `compiledQuery(testMatch)`. That should give you a `bool`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something so simple!
Would be great if you post this as answer, so I can set this as the correct one.

Comment: Why so complicated? You could just override Equals if I understand correctly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0

Comment: _"you can just say compiledQuery(testMatch)"_ and if you implement it as extension method, you can even call it like `testObject.Match(compiledQuery);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Func<T, bool>` literally means a function that takes in a `T` and returns a `bool`. In this case, it is a function that returns whether a `T` satisfies the condition or not, which is *exactly what you wanted*.

You can just call it:

```
bool satisfiesCondition = compiledQuery(testMatch);
```

You don't need to give it to `Where`. How did you think `Where` is implemented? `Where` also calls the `Func<T, bool>` you provided like this, to determine whether the object should be in the `IEnumerable<T>` it returns.